# Why is this Entity Framework code faster than its native SQL equivalent? (in MySQL)

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql, entity-framework

I'm running Entity Framework 5 in my C# .NET application, against a MySQL database using the MySQL .NET connector 6.6.5.

Usually, when EF isn't fast enough, I resort to either Stored Procedures or direct SQL execution with `context.Database.SqlQuery`  However, I recently had an issue with a SQL call actually taking far longer than its EF equivalent, and I wondered if anybody knows why this is?

Here's the (slow) SQL query:

```
public sbyte? getFirstRouteTypeFromStop(string primaryCode) {

    string sql = string.Format("SELECT r.route_type FROM stoptimes st INNER JOIN trips t ON st.trip_id = t.trip_id INNER JOIN routes r ON t.route_id = r.route_id WHERE st.stop_id = '{0}' LIMIT 1;", primaryCode);
    return context.Database.SqlQuery<sbyte?>(sql).FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Here's the (fast) EF code:

```
public sbyte? getFirstRouteTypeFromStop(string primaryCode) {

    return context.stoptimes.Where(st => st.stop_id.Equals(primaryCode)).FirstOrDefault().trip.route.route_type;

}
```

This method gets called repeatedly in a loop and EF is a LOT faster. (at least 1000%) 
Why?

Important Notes:

- The MySQL database has all these columns appropriately indexed.
- When the native SQL query is run directly in MySQL it seems to execute much faster than when run in the C# app - I suspect this is quite an important observation.

Comment: Have you looked at sql generated by EF? can you post it?

Comment: You should trace the database statements an see what EF makes of your code.

Comment: It's not a quick trace, because there's a `.FirstOrDefault()` in there, which I guess must destroy the `IQueryable` and possibly means it gets split into 2 statements?  (this is guesswork)  If I get a moment and nobody can give me a quick answer, I'll take my MySQL server down to turn on query logging and post the results.

Comment: Most likly the cause is the String.format function.. because this function supports formated output so it needs more time to analyse the complete input and replace where needed

Comment: Just call .ToString() on the IQueryable<> to see the generated SQL statement. You don't need to do anything to your server

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There is no `IQueryable<>`, since .FirstOrDefault() changes the returned type to `stoptime`.  The only way I'll really see what's happening is to log the queries on the server, and right now it's doing a 24-hour long operation!

Comment: `context.stoptimes.Where(st => st.stop_id.Equals(primaryCode))` is an IQueryable and I'll bet that if you do a ToString() before calling FirstOrDefault you will find differences. Besides, you DON'T have to profile against your production server.

Comment: Yes, `context.stoptimes.Where(st => st.stop_id.Equals(primaryCode))` is an IQueryable, what I was saying is that this will only be half of the picture, since there'll be some more SQL generated by the second half of the LINQ statement.  To get the full picture, it might be easier to just log the query on the MySQL server itself.

Comment: 1/2 a picture now may be enough

Answer (score 2):

You are using an INNER JOIN in the SqlQuery which means:

total rows selected = (no. of rows in stoptimes) * (no. of rows in routes) * (no. of rows in trips)

and then on that huge list "WHERE st.stop_id = '{0}'" is executed...
I suspect this is the problem in the sql query... the inner joins make a huge selection and filter the records from that...

Whereas the EF code filters only on the table stoptimes

```
Where(st => st.stop_id.Equals(primaryCode))
```

so it makes the filtration fast and then on the single selected record, the route and trip are fetched.

Note:- Try using LEFT OUTER JOIN... It will make your query faster.

hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for the SQL tips, but the thing is - even though this improves performance slightly - the existing query already runs really fast when executed directly in MySQL itself (see the 2nd of my 'Important Notes').  It's only when run from within EF that things slow up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have all or some `Stoptimes` (and its navigation properties like `trip` and `route`) already in memory. If this is the case, EF are just hitting databse one time (or at least not in every iteration of the loop). With `SQLQuery` you go to database in every iteration of the loop. Maybe `primaryCode` repeats a lot in the loop? or maybe you retrieve `Stoptimes` in previous code in your app without disposing context?

Comment: Hmm, this is an interesting point.  I do actually re-use the same-context each time for the loop, so perhaps EF is doing some optimisations and holding things in-memory that I hadn't expected.

Comment: I'm sure a profiler must exist for MySQL where you can see all DB hits when you execute your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the TSQL

```
SELECT r.route_type 
  FROM stoptimes st 
  JOIN trips t 
    ON st.trip_id = t.trip_id 
   AND st.stop_id = '{0}'
  JOIN routes r 
    ON t.route_id = r.route_id 
 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the SQL tips, but the thing is - even though this improves performance slightly - the existing query already runs really fast when executed directly in MySQL itself (see the 2nd of my 'Important Notes').  It's only when run from within EF that things slow up.

Comment: You need to post both TSQL coming out of EF